# How do I pass the html button value to controller?

Tags: php, laravel

**Javascript code:**

```
function f1(objButton){  
var y = objButton.value;         
window.location='panelview/($y)';}
```

Here I am just passing the value of button and I need to pass it to the controller via route.

**Controller code:**

```
public function newProduct($y)
{
    echo $y;
}
```

**Route:**

`Route::get('panelview/{y}','viewController@newProduct');`

This is what I am tried. But it echoes the same `$y` only not the value of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
window.location='panelview/($y)';
```

To

```
window.location='panelview/'+y;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
window.location='panelview/($y)';}
```

to this:

```
var y = "<?php echo ($y); ?>";
window.location='panelview/(' + y + ')';}
```